# Position of the preposition: "In the below figure, ..." or "In the figure below, ..."

Tags: prepositions, word-order

Which of the following is correct (or preferred)?

1. **"In the below figure, the effect of X on Y is clear."** *[preposition before the noun]*
2. **"In the figure below, the effect of X on Y is clear."** *[preposition after the noun]*

Do (1) and (2) differ in meaning, and if so, in what way?  Which would be preferred in a technical paper or scientific journal article?

Comment: Below isn't an adjective, so "the below figure" sounds wrong. "the figure below" sounds right and natural. (But I don't read technical paper or scientific journals as often as I'd like!)

Answer (score 1):

1

> "In the below figure, the effect of X on Y is clear." [preposition before the noun]

2

> "In the figure below, the effect of X on Y is clear." [preposition after the noun]

*below* in your example (2) is an **adverb**.  Your example (1) is uncommon.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/below)

> 3. ADVERB [**noun ADVERB**, ADVERB after verb]

> You use below in a piece of writing to refer to something that is mentioned later.

> Please contact me on the **number below**.

Please note the adverb positioning as described.